# Why does char* cause undefined behaviour while char[] doesn't?

Tags: c, string, char, undefined-behavior

Attempting to modify a string literal causes undefined behavior:

```
char * p = "wikipedia"; 
p[0] = 'W'; // undefined behaviour
```

One way to prevent this is defining it as an array instead of a pointer:

```
char p[] = "wikipedia"; 
p[0] = 'W'; // ok
```

Why does `char*` cause undefined behaviour, while `char[]` doesn't?

Comment: is this a question, or are you posting some commentary?

Comment: The question is in the ... question :-) I agree that it's a bit shoddily presented, but hey...

Comment: I've voted to reopen this.  The question is in the title.  I've edited it so the actual question is in the body.  (It could well be a duplicate, though.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any attempt to modify a C string literal has **undefined behaviour**.  A compiler may arrange for string literals to be stored in read-only memory (protected by the OS, not literally ROM unless you're on an embedded system).  But the language doesn't require this; it's up to you as a programmer to get it right.

A sufficiently clever compiler could have warned you that you should have declared the pointer as:

```
const char * p = "wikimedia";
```

though the declaration without the `const` is legal in C (for the sake of not breaking old  code).  But with or without a compiler warning, the `const` is a very good idea.

(In C++, the rules are different; C++ string literals, unlike C string literals, really are `const`.)

When you initialize an array with a literal, the literal itself still exists in a potentially read-only region of your program image, but it is *copied* into the local array:

```
char s[] = "wikimedia"; /* initializes the array with the bytes from the string */
char t[] = { 'w', 'i', ... 'a', 0 };  /* same thing */
```

<sub>Note that <s>`char u[] = *p`</s> does *not* work -- arrays can only be initialized from a brace initializer, and char arrays additionally from a string literal.</sub>

Comment: Any self-respecting programmer would have considered the const-correctness ;) ... +1

Comment: The question is tagged `C`. In `C`, the type of `"foo"` is array of char. I do not see on what basis the compiler should warn that you should have declared the pointer as ...

Comment: @Complicatedseebio: On basis that you're not allowed to mutate the contents :-) (That's what *warnings* are for.)

Comment: +1 very helpful for c++ newbies like me. I would never know I'd better precede char* with const otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Nevertheless, you are allowed to assign "foo" to a `char *` variable. Any warning there would be quite unwelcome.

Comment: @Complicatedseebio: Yes, it's allowed, and thus it's not an error. But it's something worth warning about. Like `if (n = 0)`.

Comment: No, the C standard definitely does *not* say that string literals are stored in read-only memory.  It merely says that the behavior of attempting to modify the array corresponding to a string literal is undefined.  The array is not `const`.  A warning is reasonable, but is not required.