# Array of characters initialization produces segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

The following piece of code produces a segmentation fault during compilation:

*(gdb) run 

Starting program: /home/anna/Desktop/a.out  

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 

0xb7e97845 in strtok () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6*

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main () {
char * sentence = "This is a sentence.";
char * words[200] ;
words[0] = strtok(sentence," ");
}
```

After changing the 5th line, no error is thrown.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main () {
char  sentence[] = "This is a sentence.";
char * words[200] ;
words[0] = strtok(sentence," ");
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Note: You're *executing* the program, the compilation has already successfully created the `a.out` file. It does *not* segfault "during compilation".

Comment: @WhozCraig This is not a duplicate of that question - the code in the linked question is not actually writing to a string literal, despite the title.

Comment: @interjay good point. this question is asked at least a couple of times a day. you would think it would be easily findable among the dupes. i'll keep searching. thanks.

Comment: @interjay how's [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8302326/1322972) instead ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah that seems better. I'm still not sure if this one should be closed though since the fact that `strtok` modifies the string may not be obvious.

Comment: @interjay I hope it is, since the highest up-voted answer doesn't mention it at all (`strtok()`, i mean).

Comment: That's why initializing a pointer to non-`const` `char` with a string literal is poor and dangerous practice, qualify it as `const char *`. Compilers could have many warnings that could help you avoid this problem, `gcc` has `-Wwrite-string` for example.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It should be `int main(void)`. Generally I have the idea that first reading a bit about C could help you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the `man` page of `strtok` (BUGS section),

- These functions modify their first argument.
- These functions cannot be used on constant strings.

and `char *sentence = "This is a sentence";` is allocated in read-only context, so treated as contant.

Answer (score 6):

```
char * sentence = "This is a sentence.";
```

`sentence` is a pointer pointing to a string literal *"This is a sentence."* is stored in a read only memory and you should not be modifying it.
Modifying a string literal in any way results in **Undefined Behavior** and in your case it manifests in a segmentation fault.

**Good Read:**
[What is the difference between char a[] = ?string?; and char *p = ?string?;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

Comment: And the downvote is for? Bother telling only if there is a technical reasoning.