# not able to modify strings on stack in c

Tags: c, string, stack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does char* cause undefined behaviour while char[] doesn’t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302290/why-does-char-cause-undefined-behaviour-while-char-doesnt)

The following code

```
int main() {
  char * st = "abc";
  *st = 'z';
  return 0;
}
```

is returning a segmentation fault. If the strings on the stack are not modifiable why is it not giving the error at compile time?

Comment: the string literal is read-only. declare a char *array* instead. This is a **very** common question, btw. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302290/why-does-char-cause-undefined-behaviour-while-char-doesnt/8302326#8302326), for an example.

Comment: The string is not on the stack.  It is in the Data Segment.  (the pointer to the string is on the stack).

Comment: It does not give a compile time error for compatibility reasons. The type of `"abc"` would actually be `char const[4]` which _would_ give a compiler error.

Comment: @K-ballo Not in C, `"abc"` is a `const char[4]` in C++, but in C it's a `char[4]`. One that you mustn't attempt to modify, but the type doesn't tell you that.

Answer (score 2):

The variable on the stack, st, is a pointer. The value assigned is to a string constant (read-only).

Answer (score 1):

`char *str = "this is dangerous to modify";` is not a string in the same sense you get; it's called a string-literal and modifying it produces undefined behavior according to the standard.

If you want a string that you can later modify, go like this:

```
char str[] = "Some String";
```

then modify it accordingly.