# Where do the seg fault come from in this code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does char* cause undefined behaviour while char[] doesn’t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302290/why-does-char-cause-undefined-behaviour-while-char-doesnt)

Please have a look at the code below

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    char* s = "Hello world!";
    s[0] = 'X';
    return 0;
}
```

where do the seg fault come from in this code?

**Update:**
On the contrary the code below does not give seg fault, why?

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    char s[] = "Hello world!";
    s[0] = 'X';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See the duplicate. In short, `char *s = "Hello World!";` lets `s` point to (the first character of) a string literal, and attempting to modify a string literal is undefined behaviour, often a crash because they are stored in read-only memory. `char s[] = "Hello World!";` creates a writable `char[13]`.

Comment: Can we have a separate tag for this particular dupe? `char *variable ="string"; variable[0]='ch';`? ;)

Answer (score 3):

`"Hello world!"` is a static string, you can not change it.

Comment: please see my update in question and kindly update the answer, thank you!