# Reverse strings stored in array of pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers, reverse

> Write a program to reverse the strings stored in the following array of pointers to strings:

```
char *s[ ] = {
  "To err is human...",
  "But to really mess things up...",
  "One needs to know C!!"
};
```

> Hint: write a function `xstrrev ( string )` which should reverse
>   the contents of one string. Call this function for reversing each
>   string stored in `s`.

Why am I not getting correct output with this code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

using namespace System;

void xstrrev (char str[])
{
    int i,l;
    char temp;
    l=strlen(str);

    for (i=0;i<(l/2);++i)
    {
        temp=*(str+i);
        *(str+i)=*(str+i+l-1);
        *(str+i+l-1)=temp;
    }
}

void main ()
{
char *s[] = {
        "To err is human...",
        "But to really mess things up...",
        "One needs to know C!!"
    };
    xstrrev(s[0]);
    xstrrev(s[1]);
    xstrrev(s[2]);
    puts(s[0]);
    puts(s[1]);
    puts(s[2]);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Attempting to modify a string literal causes undefined behaviour.  This question is a duplicate hundreds of times over.

Comment: Here's an example: [Why does char\* cause undefined behaviour while char\[\] doesn't?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302290/why-does-char-cause-undefined-behaviour-while-char-doesnt).

Comment: Also, `main` should return `int`, and I think you have a couple of bugs in your reverse function, too. `*(str+i+l-1)` should probably be `*(str-i+l-1)`.

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: little surprised your xstrrev() function is very nice and main() is very bad ..How ?

Comment: yes, it was supposed to be *(str-i+l-1)

Comment: problem was compiler dependent... code works well with tc..

Comment: well, for the bad main()... i saved the index variable :P...

Comment: @vaibhavtalwar The way you are writing your code look you need revers three string in order. But not reverse each string of `s[]` Am I correct ?

Comment: @vaibhavtalwar Yes if language says undefined means compiler dependent. So in TCC  it worked well. remember Linux does perform strict checking then windows. tcc is windows based.

Comment: Undefined behaviour does not have to mean "compiler dependent".  It means "undefined".  That means a particular compiler can do whatever it likes in this situation, or choose to do different things at different times for any reason or no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Are I can notice only thing you are doing wrong in declaration of `s[]`. You should declare you `s[]` in main() like this:

```
char str1[] = "To err is human...";
char str2[] = "But to really mess things up...";
char str3[] = "One needs to know C!!";
char *s[] = { str1, str2, str3};
```

Reason:

if you do like:

```
char* str = "yourname";
str[2] = 'c';    // you are trying to write on read only memory
```

you are trying to write on read only memory. that cause of segmentation fault (undefined behavior) Because `str` points to a constant string literal.

Where are if you do like:

```
char str[] = "yourname";
str[2] = 'c';    // ok no error
```

Then its ok because this time `str[]` is an array string and its value and size defined at point of declaration.

I think algorithm wise you are correct

**EDIT**  and I am correct. see here you code is working after my suggestion [**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/01DdlO3b)  and what @carlNorm said is correct. He also posted a good link.