# Error while implementing a C-API text block class in C++

Tags: c++, c, char

```
class Text
{
public :   
       char& operator[](int pos) const   
       {return text[pos];}

        char* get() const
       {return text;}
private: 
     char* text = "hello";
};
int main() 
{
     Text a;
    char * x = &a[0];
    *x = 's';
    
    cout << a.get() << endl;

}
```

I was following Scott Meyers Effective C++ book, there was a class that I had to implement myself, so  I tried implementing it my self, but this program keeps crashing.

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302290/why-does-char-cause-undefined-behaviour-while-char-doesnt

Comment: Literal strings are really arrays of **constant** characters. Attempting to modify a literal string leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Berto99 Finally! Thanks, that helped me clear my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
char* text = "hello";
```

is not valid C++, since string literals decay to a **const** char *.  With the correct command line flags, your compiler should have warned you about this.

Following on from there, `*x = 's';` results in undefined behaviour, because `x` is pointing into said string literal.  In practise, you get a seg fault, since you are trying to write to read-only memory.

---

**Edit:** Here's a fixed version using `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

class Text
{
public :   
     char& operator[](int pos) {return text[pos];}
     const char* get() const {return text.c_str ();}
private: 
     std::string text = "hello";
};

int main() 
{
    Text a;
    char * x = &a[0];
    *x = 's';
    
    std::cout << a.get() << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HRuAJRDLMvgyIleU)

Comment: Oh I get it, thanks, is there any way to fix it? because in the book it was given that way

Comment: You can probably fashion something with [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: @Xcaliber Is the book really using a pointer, or an array (as in `char text[] ="hello";`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP said he had to implement that class himself.