# Modifying string value causes access violation

Tags: c, string-literals

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    char *input = "why isn't this possible?";
    input[0] = 'W';
    return 0;
}
```

I want to modify the first value of the string, but it appears to cause an access violation on the `input[0] = 'W';` line.

Any ideas why this is happening. Oddly I don't recall this error happening on my old machine running Visual Studio, but happens with GCC and Pellas C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what your attempting to modify is not a string, it's a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal).

Yes, you see different behaviour in different cases because this attempt is mentioned to exhibit [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C standard.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.4.5, *String literals*

> *[...]If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.*

To achieve the expected output, you can simply use an array, initialized by the string literal and them attempt to modify the array element. Something like:

```
int main(void)
{
    char input[ ] = "why isn't this possible?";  // an array
    input[0] = 'W';                              // perfectly modifiable
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would I achieve what I am attempting to with C11?

Answer (score 0):

Any attempt to modify a C string literal has undefined behaviour. A compiler may arrange for string literals to be stored in read-only memory (protected by the OS, not literally ROM unless you're on an embedded system). But the language doesn't require this; it's up to you as a programmer to get it right.
Try this if you want the functionality:

```
int main()
{
    char input[] = "why isn't this possible?";
    input[0] = 'W';
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise to learn more on it, check this answer out:
[Char* and char[] and undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302290/why-does-char-cause-undefined-behaviour-while-char-doesnt)